# Problem in loading (.msh) file in fipy via Gmsh3D

Tags: python, python-2.7, 3d, mesh, fipy

I'm trying to import my mesh file (.msh) from Gmsh 4.7.0  into FiPy==3.4.2.1 (Windows 10)(Python 2.7.9).
This mesh was created using open source FEM software (Cast3M) and then it was exported to Gmsh as .MED file. Gmsh was viewing perfectly my mesh without any problem with the same number of elements and nodes.
Then I proceed to export the mesh as .msh file from Gmsh. (File----Export----msh file---save).
I was doing:

```
mesh=fp.Gmsh3D('cylinder.msh') #After importing fipy
```

So I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<itasca-code-2-53a6529af1f3>", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Youssef Fawaz\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\fipy\meshes\gmshMesh.py", line 1993, in __init__
    self._orderedCellVertexIDs_data) = self.mshFile.read()
  File "C:\Users\Youssef Fawaz\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\fipy\meshes\gmshMesh.py", line 813, in read
    raise GmshException(errStr)
fipy.meshes.gmshMesh.GmshException: Gmsh hasn't produced any cells! Check your Gmsh code.

Gmsh output:
Info    : Running 'gmsh c:\users\yousse~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpoqqytw.geo -3 -nopopup -format msh2 -o c:\users\yousse~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpygqpw3.msh' [Gmsh 4.7.0, 1 node, max. 1 thread]
Info    : Started on Fri Nov 13 10:31:12 2020
Info    : Reading 'c:\users\yousse~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpoqqytw.geo'...
Info    : Done reading 'c:\users\yousse~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpoqqytw.geo'
Info    : Meshing 1D...
Info    : Done meshing 1D (Wall 0s, CPU 0s)
Info    : Meshing 2D...
Info    : Done meshing 2D (Wall 0s, CPU 0s)
Info    : Meshing 3D...
Info    : Done meshing 3D (Wall 0s, CPU 0s)
Info    : 0 nodes 0 elements
Info    : Writing 'c:\users\yousse~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpygqpw3.msh'...
Info    : Done writing 'c:\users\yousse~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpygqpw3.msh'
Info    : Stopped on Fri Nov 13 10:31:12 2020 (From start: Wall 0.00300002s, CPU 0s)
```

To be noted that I'm implementing this mesh in DEM code (PFC3D developed by Itasca) coupling with fipy. For instance the problem is importing my mesh (not my code problem).
Here is the link for my files (.msh, .MED) and the image of my mesh in Gmsh3D
[files](https://filesender.renater.fr/?s=download&token=05e3e586-4cdb-4cac-a0f1-07bf8caa5707).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FiPy only understands the [`msh2` format](http://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#MSH-file-format-version-2-_0028Legacy_0029) from Gmsh. Export from Gmsh with `-format msh2`.

Comment: It's working! (after changing also the headers in the file from $parametricNodes to Nodes). Could you tell me please which version of Gmsh is compatible with Fipy 3.1?.Mr @jeguyer thank you very much!

Comment: @youssef I assume you don't really mean FiPy 3.1; that was released seven years ago! FiPy can currently work with Gmsh 3 or 4, but it cannot understand the latest `msh` formats from Gmsh 4. I don't know what `$parametricNodes` are. They are not mentioned in the [`MSH` documentation](http://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#MSH-file-format).

Comment: Actually my code is written using Fipy 3.1(the test that I did was with fipy3.4.2.1 and Gmsh 4.7.0).And If I write `fp.Gmsh3D` it will show me that Gmsh is implemented in this version 3.1 of Fipy.So I'm wondering which version of Gmsh is compatible with fipy 3.1;because I got this error:EnvironmentError: Gmsh version must be >= 2.0. (Note: I put the Gmsh.exe in the file scripts of python)

Comment: I have no idea what this means: "Fipy 3.1(the test that I did was with fipy3.4.2.1". The comments are no place to sort this out. Please ask a new question about this "`Gmsh version must be >= 2.0.`" issue. Our [mailing list](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/MAIL.html) or [issue tracker](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues) are probably better places to troubleshoot than StackOverflow.